# How do I cast Qt's QVariant to boost::any?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

How do I cast Qt's QVariant to boost::any?

Comment: what do you mean boost::any? 
can you explain little more what exactly you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i dont think there is an easy way, i would do following:

```
boost::any qvariant_to_any(const QVariant& v) {
    switch(v.userType()) {
        case QVariant::Bool:
            return boost::any(v.value<bool>());
            //or: return boost::any(v.toBool());
        case QVariant::Int:
            return boost::any(v.value<int>());
            //or: return boost::any(v.toInt());
        case QVariant::UInt:
            return boost::any(v.value<unsigned>());
        // ...
        // all your types which store in a QVariant in your use case
        case QVariant::Invalid:
        default:
            throw std::bad_cast(); //or return default constructed boost::any
    }
}
```

if Boost.Variant would do the job aswell instead of Boost.Any, in a german magazin there was a nice article about converting QVariant to Boost.Variant and vice versa, take a look at the source code if this interrests you:

german article: http://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/Konvertierungen-992950.html

source:  ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ix/developer/elfenbein.zip

Answer (score 6):

I hope to save some people some typeing by elaborating on smerlin's great answer.

```
boost::any QVariantToAny(const QVariant& v) {
    switch(v.userType()) {
        case QVariant::BitArray:
            return boost::any(v.value<QBitArray>());
        case QVariant::Bitmap:
            return boost::any(v.value<QBitmap>());
        case QVariant::Bool:
            return boost::any(v.value<bool>());
        case QVariant::Brush:
            return boost::any(v.value<QBrush>());
        case QVariant::ByteArray:
            return boost::any(v.value<QByteArray>());
        case QVariant::Char:
            return boost::any(v.value<QChar>());
        case QVariant::Color:
            return boost::any(v.value<QColor>());
        case QVariant::Cursor:
            return boost::any(v.value<QCursor>());
        case QVariant::Date:
            return boost::any(v.value<QDate>());
        case QVariant::DateTime:
            return boost::any(v.value<QDateTime>());
        case QVariant::Double:
            return boost::any(v.value<double>());
        case QVariant::EasingCurve:
            return boost::any(v.value<QEasingCurve>());
        case QVariant::Font:
            return boost::any(v.value<QFont>());
        case QVariant::Hash:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVariantHash>());
        case QVariant::Icon:
            return boost::any(v.value<QIcon>());
        case QVariant::Image:
            return boost::any(v.value<QImage>());
        case QVariant::Int:
            return boost::any(v.value<int>());
        case QVariant::KeySequence:
            return boost::any(v.value<QKeySequence>());
        case QVariant::Line:
            return boost::any(v.value<QLine>());
        case QVariant::LineF:
            return boost::any(v.value<QLineF>());
        case QVariant::List:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVariantList>());
        case QVariant::Locale:
            return boost::any(v.value<QLocale>());
        case QVariant::LongLong:
            return boost::any(v.value<qlonglong>());
        case QVariant::Map:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVariantMap>());
        case QVariant::Matrix:
            return boost::any(v.value<QMatrix>());
        case QVariant::Transform:
            return boost::any(v.value<QTransform>());
        case QVariant::Matrix4x4:
            return boost::any(v.value<QMatrix4x4>());
        case QVariant::Palette:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPalette>());
        case QVariant::Pen:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPen>());
        case QVariant::Pixmap:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPixmap>());
        case QVariant::Point:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPoint>());
        case QVariant::PointArray:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPointArray>());
        case QVariant::PointF:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPointF>());
        case QVariant::Polygon:
            return boost::any(v.value<QPolygon>());
        case QVariant::Quaternion:
            return boost::any(v.value<QQuaternion>());
        case QVariant::Rect:
            return boost::any(v.value<QRect>());
        case QVariant::RectF:
            return boost::any(v.value<QRectF>());
        case QVariant::RegExp:
            return boost::any(v.value<QRegExp>());
        case QVariant::Region:
            return boost::any(v.value<QRegion>());
        case QVariant::Size:
            return boost::any(v.value<QSize>());
        case QVariant::SizeF:
            return boost::any(v.value<QSizeF>());
        case QVariant::SizePolicy:
            return boost::any(v.value<QSizePolicy>());
        case QVariant::String:
            return boost::any(v.value<QString>());
        case QVariant::StringList:
            return boost::any(v.value<QStringList>());
        case QVariant::TextFormat:
            return boost::any(v.value<QTextFormat>());
        case QVariant::TextLength:
            return boost::any(v.value<QTextLength>());
        case QVariant::Time:
            return boost::any(v.value<QTime>());
        case QVariant::UInt:
            return boost::any(v.value<unsigned>());
        case QVariant::ULongLong:
            return boost::any(v.value<qulonglong>());
        case QVariant::Url:
            return boost::any(v.value<QUrl>());
        case QVariant::Vector2D:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVector2D>());
        case QVariant::Vector3D:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVector3D>());
        case QVariant::Vector4D:
            return boost::any(v.value<QVector4D>());
        case QVariant::UserType: 
        case QVariant::Invalid:
        default:
            throw std::bad_cast(); //or return default constructed boost::any
    }
}
```